# Publish link to literal orgmode file

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How can you publish an Org-mode file `main.org` to `main.html` which contains a link to a literal Org-mode file `sample.org`?

If you put `[[file:sample.org][This is a sample Org-mode file]]` in `main.org` then `sample.org` will be exported and published as `sample.html`

The desired result is to have a `main.html` which contains a link to the literal `sample.org` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to have a separate section in `org-publish-project-alist` to copy the source files into a `.../sources/` directory. Then use an explicit `http` link in `main.org` to refer to the `sample.org` file: that link is not touched by the export. The trick is to make sure that the `http` link in `main.org` refers to where the `sample.org` file will end up after publishing the project.

This suggestion comes from the manual: see the [Publishing links](https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-links.html) section.